# Are there any other interesting languages frozen in time like Common Lisp?

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms, multiple-languages

By that I mean languages where they are stable and the standard has stopped being actively worked on, and they offer something interesting by studying them.

I am not looking for normal imperative /procedural languages that have stopped being worked on (i.e. C-like) unless of course it was something that c is based off like ALGOL.

They can be languages that run on any platform (not just unix/osx/win), it can run on a toaster for all I care, I just want it to be something interesting.

I am looking to be amazed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check an esoteric languages.
There is a site, [esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org) that has a huge list of the esoteric languages, an informations about paradigms/concepts, a list of ideas and many more.
From the esolangs.org, the esoteric language is:

> An esoteric programming language is a computer programming language
>   designed to experiment with weird ideas, to be hard to program in, or
>   as a joke, rather than for practical use.

Here are some examples from that site:

- [BF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BF) - using just a `><+-.,[]` symbols
- [Piet](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet) - image as a source code